# Три div'a неверно отображаются в IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Опять с версткой проблемы.
Есть 3 дива, которые должны выводиться в строку. В Opera и FF все замечательно, но IE делает непонятные отступы от центрального дива по бокам.
Вот так отображается в IE:

[ссылка](http://savepic.su/115139.png)

Вот так отображается в Opera и также должно быть в IE

[ссылка](http://savepic.su/108995.png)

Код только дивов в index.html:

```
<div class="all_content">
     <div class="left_top"></div><div class="right_top"></div><div class="center_top">       </div>
</div>
     <div class="all_content">
     <div class="left_top"></div><div class="right_top"></div><div class="center_top"> </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.all_content {
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.left_top {
width: 340px;
height: 202px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
border-top: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
position: relative;
float:left;
color: #696969;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
}

.center_top {
width: 320px;
height: 202px;
border: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
position: relative;
color: #696969;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
}
.right_top {
width: 340px;
height: 202px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
border-top: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
position: relative;
float:right;
color: #696969;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: возможно смог бы помоч, да к сожалению скрины у меня не отображаются почему то ... может перезальете ? 


Comment: Вообщем, все что ниже - все не то. Везде криво. А скрины перезалил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="all_content>
    <div class="left_top"></div>
    <div class="center_top"></div>
    <div class="right_top"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
 .all_content {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-family: 11px Tahoma;
    color: #696969;
}
.left_top {
    width: 340px;
    height: 202px;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f8fc;*/
    /*border-top: 2px solid #f5f8fc;*/
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue; /* включено для нагладности */
}

.center_top {
    width: 320px;
    height: 202px;
    /*border: 2px solid #f5f8fc;*/
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: pink; /* включено для нагладности */
}
.right_top {
    width: 340px;
    height: 202px;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f8fc;*/
    /*border-top: 2px solid #f5f8fc;*/
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 660px; /* ВНИМАНИЕ -  это значение равно ширине "левого" и "центрального" дива + ширина "левых" и "правых" границ "левого" и "центрального" дива + ширина "левого" border "правого" дива. То есть, если брать знаxения ширины ваших div и border оно будет равно 664px; */
    background-color: black; /* включено для нагладности */
}
```

Работает в IE7+

Comment: Незнаю что вы тестировали в IE, но все воообще вообще криво.

Comment: Посмотрите изменена расстановка div.
Создайте чистый файл и проверьте - все работает.
Надеюсь вы пользуетесь reset.css

Comment: Почти получилось. Теперь в IE левый и центральный дивы соеденились вместе, но переместились до упора влево. А правый диз отсоединен от них.

Comment: Попробывал с ИЕ комментариями, все равно не получается. Помогите!

Answer (score 1):

Евгений, проблема элементарная, решается многими способами.

1. `* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}` - обнуляем все отступы для всех элементов.
2. `block { display: inline; }` - убирает специфические отступы у блоков в ie.
3. Вот ссылка на будущее для лечения всяких "болезней", точно поможет: [ссылка-врач](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/glyuki-brauzerov/ie6/margin-float-block-v-ie6.html).

Comment: Значит у Вас где-то косякили или Вы что-то не так делаете, у меня была аналогичная ситуация - помогло.Может пойти поспать? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.center_top{margin:0 340px}
.all_content:after{display:block;clear:both;content:'';height:0px;}
```

добавьте

Comment: Проблема осталась. Не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Создай отдельный .css для ie(версия),через комментарий укажи что специально для ie(версия)(в head добавь).

Подверстай уже спецом под ie.

p.s скрины не отображаются.

Answer (score 0):

вероятно то что Вам нужно выглядит так

```
<div class="all_content">
     <div class="left_top"></div><div class="center_top"></div><div class="right_top"></div>
</div>
<div class="all_content">
     <div class="left_top"></div><div class="center_top"></div><div class="right_top"></div>
</div>
<style>
.all_content {
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
display:table;
clear:both;
}
.left_top {
width: 340px;
height: 202px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
border-top: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
position: relative;
float:left;
color: #696969;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
}

.center_top {
width: 340px;
height: 202px;
border: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
position: relative;
color: #696969;
float:left;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
}
.right_top {
width: 340px;
height: 202px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
border-top: 2px solid #f5f8fc;
position: relative;
float:left;
color: #696969;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Не помогло